# ASP.NET Core 2.1 can't access cookies from Razor document in production

Tags: asp.net, .net, cookies, razor, asp.net-core

So I recently migrated to .NET Core 2.1 from MVC 5. In a razor file I check for the existence of a cookie, and if it doesn't exist I render some html.

```
@{
    if (Context.Request.Cookies["cookie_name"] == null)
    {
        <p>html</p>
    }
}
```

This works fine in development and staging environments, but it never detects the cookie in my production environment so it renders the html every time, even when the cookie is clearly set.

My development environment is https like my production environment.

Comment: Can you see the cookie in the browser? (in Developer Tools)

Comment: Yep. Actually weird thing is that it behaves correctly when developer tools is open and cache is disabled. But when I enable cache it stops working again even though I can see the cookies in the request.

Comment: @OliverReznik Please share your Startup.cs file code here please?

Comment: paste the start up file. You can hide some info

Comment: have you tried running in visual studio with production assigned?